# How can I make my section hide only after the submit button is pressed. right now the section disappears after I press one letter

Tags: vue.js

vue.js, how can I make my section hide only after the submit button is pressed. right now the section disappears after I press one letter. I want the V-if and V-else to activate only after the user has submitted their request. or if routing the results on to a different page would easier id like to go that route also.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">

   
        <section id="whiteClawVideo" class="videoWrapper d-block w-100">
           <div class="video-container fluid">
            <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JORN2hkXLyM? 
autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div>
          </section>
   

     
     <form @submit.prevent="SearchMovies()" class="search-box">
       <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for? " v-model="search" />
       <input type="submit" value="Search">
     </form>
     
     
    
     <div class="movies-list"  v-if="search !== ''" >
       <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-3"   v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.imdbID">
         <router-link :to="'/movie/'+movie.imdbID" class="movie-link">
             <img class="movieImg" height="100%" :src="movie.Poster" alt="Movie Poster" />
               <div class="type">{{ movie.Type }}</div>
                <div class="detail">
                  <p class="year">{{movie.Year}}</p>
                  <h3>{{ movie.Title }}</h3>
                  <p>{{movie.imdbID}}</p>
                </div>
         </router-link>
       </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
     <div  class="container" v-else>
       <MovieSection />
       <SecondMovieSection />
     </div>


  </div>
  
</template>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import env from '@/env.js';
import MovieSection from '@/components/MovieSection.vue';
import SecondMovieSection from '@/components/SecondMovieSection.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MovieSection,
    SecondMovieSection
  },
  setup () {
    const search = ref("");
    const movies = ref([]);

    const SearchMovies = () => {
      if (search.value !== "") {
        fetch(`API_HERE`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          movies.value = data.Search;
          
          
        })
      }
    }

    return {
      search,
      movies,
      SearchMovies
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: add a data variable that gets updated when you press submit (your SearchMovies function can do it) when that variable is true, hide

Answer (score 0):

Well, it closes once you type a single character because search is a model - it updates on every keypress you do within input it's bound to. What you wanna do instead is hide form based on whether you have entries in your movies array or not, so try changing `v-if="search !== ''"` to `v-if="!movies.length"`

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a new boolean ref, let's say "isSubmitted", and set it to true in the beginning of your SearchMovies function. Then in the template set it to `v-if="!isSubmitted"`. Thus the form will hide as soon as you submit the form rather then once data is fetched